# RAILS: Popup/warning/message before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show a popup/message saying `update some other table also` based on a particular field while creating a record.

Is there a way to do it using validations or action links?

I want to do something like below:

```
validates :fieldc, if: :should_update?, message: "Update fielda and fieldb in tablex also"

bef should_update?
  fieldc == "req_value"
end
```

I am sure the above validation won't work. But I want to show the popup if `fieldc == req_value` and the record should be created. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
can I do it the following way?

```
  after_create :update_tablex
  def update_tablex
      if self.should_update?
        flash[:notice] = 'Please update fielda and fieldb in tablex also'
      else
        flash[:notice] = 'Record updated successfully.'
      end
  end


def should_update?
  fieldc == "req_value"
end
```

But Iam still getting the `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'flash' for #)`

Comment: Can you please be more clear? What do you mean by form?

Comment: Keeping it simple, Is there a way to show a popup message in rails module on performing create new action?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a controller issue, and should be addressed in the controller, not the model.  The model is never responsible for controlling the logic of what's viewed and how the workflow progresses.  Best bet would be to set a flash message that shows what they need to do, and as a convenience redirect them to the tablex edit view.

in your create method...

```
def create
  ... 
  if @record.save
    if @record.should_update?
      flash[:notice] = 'Please update fielda and fieldb in tablex also'
      redirect_to edit_tablex_path(@record.tablex)
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Record updated successfully.'
      redirect_to @record
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a pretty solid approach

Comment: I am getting the following error: `NameError (undefined local variable or method `flash' for #)`

Comment: Sorry, forgot an equals sign in my fifth line.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: I think it's not about the equal sign.. I already corrected it in my code and it still shows the same error!

or can I do it the following way?

      after_create :update_tablex
      def update_tablex
          if self.should_update?
            flash[:notice] = 'Please update fielda and fieldb in tablex also'
          else
            flash[:notice] = 'Record updated successfully.'
          end
      end

    
    def should_update?
      fieldc == "req_value"
    end

Comment: Please check my edit and let me know if I can do it that way.

Comment: No flash is not available in the model.  My code was meant to go into the controller class... Is that where you put it?

Comment: Nope, after_create is not working in the controller.. So, I moved it to model.

Comment: It should NOT be in the model, it's not a model responsibility.

Comment: If you insist on using `after_save` consider using an Observer. https://github.com/rails/rails-observers